# How to access UI control from code-behind of ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

So I have a ResourceDictionary to define my custom Window style. What I am struggling to do is to access controls from XAML file.
The ResourceDictionary looks like this

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Style x:Key="MyCustomWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">

    <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
        <Setter.Value>
            <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="30"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                <Grid>
                    <!-- the root window -->
                    <Border BorderThickness="0.3" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource GeneralDarkBlue}">
                        <AdornerDecorator>
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </AdornerDecorator>
                    </Border>

                    <DockPanel Height="30" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" VerticalAlignment="Top" LastChildFill="False">

                        <Viewbox x:Name="HamburgerMenu" DockPanel.Dock="Left" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True">
                            <Viewbox.InputBindings>
                                <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" Command="{Binding SettingsClick}"/>
                            </Viewbox.InputBindings>
                            <Border Width="47" Height="32" Background="Transparent">
                                <Canvas>
                                    <Path x:Name="TopbarIconHamburgerMenu" Margin="14,10" Data="M12.5,19h19.2v1H12.5V19z M12.5,13.7h19.2v1H12.5V13.7z M12.5,8.5h19.2v1H12.5V8.5z" Stretch="UniformToFill" Fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                                </Canvas>
                            </Border>
                        </Viewbox>

                        // the rest of viewboxes for minimize, maximize controls...

                    </DockPanel>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

</Style>
```

And let's say I want to access the HamburgerMenu, so I do something like this

```
 public partial class MyCustomWindowStyle : ResourceDictionary
 {
        public MyCustomWindowStyle()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void DoSomething()
        {
            var window = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["MyCustomWindowStyle"];
            var hm = (Viewbox)window.Resources.FindName("HamburgerMenu");
        }
}
```

and this returns null in the hm!

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Have you set your build action to Resource?

Comment: The MyCustomWindowStyle.xaml is set to Page build action. And the MyCustomWindowStyle.xaml.cs is set to Compile. If I set the first to Resource, I take the error "The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: "HamburgerMenu" is not in the Resources list for your style. It's a child element inside of the ControlTemplate. So you'll have to read through the children of the Grid inside of the ControlTemplate until you get to "HamburgerMenu". Hope this helps!

Comment: @Fireboyd78 thank you for your comment, but it isn't that helpful because I don't know how to do that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First of all**, `Style.Resource` is a `ResourceDictionary`, and there are two important things to notice in the `ResourceDictionary.FindName` method [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.findname(v=vs.110).aspx):

Summary section saying:

> Not supported by this Dictionary implementation.

and *Return Value* section saying:

> Always returns **null**.

**Second of all**, even if you tried to retrieve the `ViewBox` by key, it would have to be defined as a resource:

```
<Style x:Key="MyCustomWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <ViewBox x:Key="HamburgerMenu" />
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

And it is not. It is a part of `ControlTemplate`'s visual tree.

**Third of all**, `ControlTemplate` does not contain actual elements, but rather a recipe for creating them. So there's no actual `ViewBox` living inside the `ControlTemplate` to retrieve. Notice that `ControlTemplate.FindName` takes an additional parameter specifying an element for which the template was **realized**.

However, `ControlTemplate` does have a `LoadContent` method, which basically loads the visual tree defined by that template, and I think you could use it, and then invoke `FindName` on the root element. To simplify retrieval of the `ControlTemplate` let's first make it a resource:

```
<Style x:Key="MyCustomWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="Template" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Grid>
                (...)
                    <ViewBox x:Key="HamburgerMenu" />
                (...)
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource Template}" />
</Style>
```

Then this should do the trick for you:

```
var window = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["MyCustomWindowStyle"];
var template = (ControlTemplate)window.Resources["Template"];
var root = (FrameworkElement)template.LoadContent();
var hm = (ViewBox)root.FindName("HamburgerMenu");
```

---

### Update

If your goal is to get hold of the `ViewBox` in an existing window with that template applied, first you need to know how to get hold of that particular window. It could be the `Application.Current.MainWindow`, otherwise you're highly likely to find it in the `Application.Current.Windows` collection. You could also implement the singleton pattern for that window, or use other methods like exposing a static property with reference to that window somewhere in your application, or using third-party tools, such as [Service Locator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921142.aspx) in *Prism*.

Once you have the window in your hand, you only need to use the previously mentioned `ControlTemplate.FindName` method:

```
var window = (...);
var hm = (ViewBox)window.Template.FindName(name: "HamburgerMenu", templatedParent: window);
```

Note that accessing the resource dictionary in which the template was defined is not necessary.

As for why your attempts with previous solution failed - that's because `ControlTemplate.LoadContent` method yields freshly created element each time it is invoked, and modifying it does not reflect on elements previously created by that template.

Comment: thank you very much for your time and the really nice explanation. However, there are still some issues. First, I still can't set x:Key in the Viewbox. I get the error "key attribute can only be used in an IDictionary". 
But I left it as x:Name and the code worked... until I tried to set the hm.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; and it did nothing! It didn't hide the control. Am I missing something or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Yes, I think you've misunderstood how templates work. As I said, a template is basically a recipe for creating a visual tree, and it only "knows" how to create such visual tree, and not how to locate previously created one in the abyss of your application. You, as a programmer, need to keep track of those. See my updated answer.

Comment: I admit that I still have a lot to learn about XAML, templates, etc. Many many thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Grx70 I have similar issue posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64430409/1232087) - in case you have time for a suggestion/comment or a solution. Thank you.